# Summing differences across "i"

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to sum the difference across "i" according to the following formula:

[image: formula]

where f is a 15x1 array of zeros and ones, which looks like:

```
[[1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]]
```

and M is a 8 x 15 matrix also of zeros and ones, the first row of which is:

```
[0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
```

"f" is inside a while loop and changes with each iteration, so I need to do this lots of times. I want to implement the above formula, so that each element in f is subtracted from the corresponding element of M(C, i), and then absolute values are taken, and those values are summed. From calculating by hand this value should be 10, so it is clear my current approach is wrong (this returns 117):

```
(np.sum(abs(f - M[C,])))
```

I might be missing something obvious here, can anyone advise? When I try to loop in range(0,15), I am also off.

Comment: Try `(np.sum(abs(f.reshape(f.shape[0]) - M)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the subtraction, you want `f` to [broadcast](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) across `M`. To do this the shapes must be compatible. `f` needs to be [reshaped](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
f.reshape(-1) - M
```

---

```
f = np.random.random_integers(0,1,(15,1))
M = np.random.random_integers(0,1,(5,15))

>>> f.shape
(15, 1)
>>> M.shape
(5, 15)

>>> g = f.reshape(-1)
>>> g.shape
(15,)
>>> g
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
>>> g - M
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  0, -1, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1, -1, -1,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
>>>
```

[`.ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel) also works.

```
>>> f.ravel()
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
>>> f.ravel() - M
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  0, -1, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  1, -1, -1,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
>>>
```

Finally:

```
>>> np.sum(np.absolute(f.reshape(-1) - M))
30
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the question directly, you could do something like

```
np.sum(np.abs(f.T - M[C])
```

For example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
f = np.random.choice([0, 1], (15, 1))
M = np.random.choice([0, 1], (8, 15))
C = 0
np.sum(np.abs(f.T - M[C]))  # 7
```

To get the results for all rows at once, you could use

```
np.sum(np.abs(f.T - M), axis=1)  # [7, 7, 6, 9, 8, 5, 9, 7]
```